# Angular2 visual cues for required fields

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following markup

### .html

```
  <div
      class = "mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-group">
    <input
        required
        type = "text"
        pattern = "{{regex}}"
        [(ngModel)] = "name.first"
        ngControl = "first"
        #first = "ngForm"
        class = "mdl-textfield__input form-control"
        id = "first">
    <label
        class = "mdl-textfield__label"
        for = "first">First</label>
    <span *ngIf = "showErrorMsg()"
          class =
              "mdl-textfield__error">{{msg}}</span>
  </div>
```

Does angular2 (and angular2-dart) have any built-in visual-cues to indicate to the user that a field is required?

Thanks

Comment: See section "Add Custom CSS for Visual Feedback" in the [Forms doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).

Comment: I read that Mark. My question relates more to some cue when the application initializes. I don't like the idea for all required inputs to display invalid message at initialization time. Some application use a red asterisk for instance. Any thoughts on that. Thhanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cue you mention when the form initializes is the pristine state. There are 3 states a form field can have: touched/untouched, pristine/dirty and valid/invalid.

You have to play with all 3 to get the styling effect you want. For example:

```
form input.ng-invalid, form input.ng-pristine.ng-invalid:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

form input.ng-pristine {
    border: 1px solid dimgrey;
}
```

This causes all fields when the form starts (pristine) to be grey (normal color). If the user touches the field and its required, it will be red. But if the user immediately clicks away without editing the field it will become grey.

If the user types a value but the field is still invalid, it will remain red even if the user clicks away. This is the more intuitive way to use these styles. Marking everything as invalid at start, or putting a field in red just because the user touched is not a good user experience.

Check this running [code example](https://github.com/jhades/blog.jhades.org/tree/master/angular2-forms) of this styling in action.

Comment: For google's material design input (text) how would your suggestions apply, remembering that the input is somewhat different from a standard input (type='text')

Comment: How about the style for valid field. I'm having problem styling valid field for optional field and required field.